# Install TeamViewer on macOS using terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, teamviewer

I want to install TeamViewer on macOS using terminal. I know that I can AppleScript to do this, but then TeamViewer UI's will pop up and I have to complete the graphical installation.

Using AppleScript I need to use System Events, the user will then need to do some steps himself in the system prefs to allow this. This is not what I want since the users of the app I'm developing probably have less computer knowledge that the average grandmother...

I'm wondering if it is possible to install TeamViewer using some terminal command. I know that I can install it using homebrew, but is not the result that I want since a lot of other, probably (for the user) useless packages, will be installed on their systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the package (contained in the `.dmg`you download) like this:

`sudo installer -pkg "Install TeamViewer.pkg" -target /`

However this results in the the *Initial Setup* screen.

[image]

According to their documentation:

> Silent installation is only supported for the (Customized) Host at the moment. Support for the Full Client is planned though for the near future.

See [Mass deployment on macOS](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Mass-deployment-on-macOS/ta-p/50739)

This *Initial Setup* is optional and can be completed later.  However while you could end it via terminal with (for example) `pkill TeamViewer` this results in a *TeamViewer ended unexpectedly* error which would probably be more confusing to users than completing the screen themselves.

Comment: Thanks, at this time we’re using the installer command with applescript to walk through the initial setup. It’s a bummer that silent install is not yet available for the full client. I’m keeping the question open to see if someone else has a different solution!

Comment: You can kill the *Initial Setup* screen and TeamViewer still works after but the error message would look terrible.

Comment: I agree, probably better when the users goes through the initial setup screen